# JDBC on SQL Server, executeQuery() cannot find the result with null

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I use jdbc to retrieve data from SQL Server, and ANSI_NULLS is off . So if I run

```
select * from cj_log where evt = null
```

I can get the result.

But when I put it in a statement like this

```
Statement st = DBConnection.getConnection().createStatement();
String sql = "select * from CJ_LOG where EVT=null";
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

The result set is empty. What is the problem here?

Comment: What happens when you use  `select * from CJ_LOG where EVT IS NULL` ?

Comment: ANSI_NULLS is a per-connection setting. If `DBConnection.getConnection()` is not ensuring that ANSI_NULLS is OFF, it is likely that ANSI_NULLS is in fact ON (the default).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to say

```
where EVT is null
```

Nothing is ever equal to null, even null.

Think of it like this: Null means "don't know".

You are asking "is something I don't know equal to something I don't know"

The answer is "I don't know". So you don't get any rows.

Comment: While you are absolutely right in terms of the SQL standard, if, as the question indicated, the SQL Server is actually running with ANSI_NULLs off, `select * from CJ_LOG where EVT = NULL` is actually equivalent to `select * from CJ_LOG where EVT IS NULL`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx).

Comment: Point. Bottom line is "turn ANSI_NULLS on and leave it on". :-)

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you all for the help.